# Convert bigDecimal to String from db

Tags: java, jdbc, bigdecimal

I am retrieving data from a database and the customer id is a big decimal:

```
public List<Data> getData() {
    log.info("get getData");

    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL_SELECT_DATA);
    for(Map row : rows) {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setCustId((String)row.get("CUST_ID"));
        data.setProjectId((String)row.get("PROJECT_ID"));
        data.setProjectName((String)row.get("PROJECT_NAME"));

        //add the data object to the list
        dataList.add(data);
    }
    return dataList;    
}
```

Any suggestions what would be a quick and easy way to convert the `"CUST_ID"` to a `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

umm, `data.setCustId(row.get("CUST_ID").toString())` ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :   `data.setCustId(""+row.get("CUST_ID"));`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Lodder why it doesn't provide an answer ?did you check the  accepted answer ?

Comment: It may not be an efficient answer, but it does answer the question.